# How to loop with regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

```
re.compile(regex1)
r1=r.sub(something,text)
re.compile(regex2)
r2=r.sub(something,text)
re.compile(regex3)
r3=r.sub(something,text)
```

So I want to change a text based on three regexpressions.. but i dont know how to apply three of them and reproduce it as one whole. Can anyone please help me out with how to go about this

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: What kind of changes you want to do on your string?

Comment: for example replace words ending with first case:ing with ring,second case 2: replace 0's with ring: case 3: replace > with ring. What i am trying to say the three cases may be different  but what its being replaced with is same

Comment: @ananymous59 can you please add you explain to your question?

Comment: You mean, like `re.sub(r"ing|0|>", "ring", text)`?

Comment: yea!!! something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your regular expressions are rather simple, you could just create a disjunction from your several regular expression and replace them all at once:

```
>>> text = "something with 0 and >"
>>> re.sub(r"ing|0|>", "ring", text)
'somethring with ring and ring'
```

Alternatively, you can use a loop, or just replace them one after another, but make sure to replace the text in the result of the previous replacement, not in the original text!

I.e., using your pseudo-code, it should be something like this:

```
r = re.compile(regex1)
r1 = r.sub(something, text)
re.compile(regex2)
r2 = r.sub(something, r1) # use r1 here
re.compile(regex3)
r3 = r.sub(something, r2) # and r2 here
```

Or just assign back to your original `text` variable:

```
for x in ["ing", "0", ">"]:
    text = re.sub(x, "ring", text)
print text
```

(Of course, you have to make sure to replace `ing` before replacing the other things with `ring`, otherwise the `ing` in `ring` will be replaced again!)

Comment: tnx a lot that was what i was looking for...sorry my question was not clear